# What type of list is best for calling specific items?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of spaces with associated square-footages in a dict. I want to call each item and use its area to form dimensions with a simple area/width equation...then re-associate the dimensions with the space name. I've learned that dicts are un-indexed and unsorted. Thanks in advance!

```
#program areas
ticketing_sqft=600
galleries_sqft=12500
auditorium_sqft=2000
conference_sgft=1600


#dict of areas
sqft=dict(ticketing_sqft=600, galleries_sqft=12500, auditorium_sqft=2000,
      conference_sgft=1600)
program_names=list(sqft.keys())
areas=list(sqft.values())
areas.sort()
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make any sense out of your question.  What are you trying to do and what doesn't work?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  A dict isn't a type of list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define your dictionary:

```
>>> sqft=dict(ticketing_sqft=600, galleries_sqft=12500, auditorium_sqft=2000, conference_sgft=1600)
```

#### Assuming a perfect square

Now, let's make a dictionary of the width, length that the area would have if it was a perfect square:

```
>>> wh = {bldg:(area**0.5, area**0.5) for (bldg, area) in sqft.items()}
```

The new dictionary looks like:

```
>>> print wh
{'auditorium_sqft': (44.721359549995796, 44.721359549995796), 'conference_sgft': (40.0, 40.0), 'ticketing_sqft': (24.49489742783178, 24.49489742783178), 'galleries_sqft': (111.80339887498948, 111.80339887498948)}
```

#### Assuming a Golden Rectangle

Ancient mathematicians would argue that rectangles look best if their sides were in proportional to the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).  If that is the case for your buildings, then use:

```
>>> r = (1 + 5**0.5)/2
>>> wh = {bldg:((area/r)**0.5, (area*r)**0.5) for (bldg, area) in sqft.items()}
>>> print wh
{'auditorium_sqft': (35.15775842541429, 56.88644810057831), 'conference_sgft': (31.446055110296932, 50.880785980562756), 'ticketing_sqft': (19.256697360916718, 31.15799084103365), 'galleries_sqft': (87.89439606353574, 142.21612025144577)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
sq_dict = {"ticketing_sqft": 600, "galleries_sqft": 12500, "auditorium_sqft": 2000, "conference_sqft": 1600}

lenwid_dict = {}
for key in sq_dict:
    lenwid_dict[key] = [sq_dict[key]/2, sq_dict[key]/3] # any formula here

print lenwid_dict
```

Essentially loop through the key/value pairs in our square footage dictionary and create a length/width dictionary based on operations on our square footage dictionary values.